I am facing a problem while updating the Tauri app.exe icon
In tauri.conf.json in bundle I have updated all icons but still app.exe file is not showing the icons. Is there any other way to update the icon?
In tauri.conf.json
"icon": [
        "icons/32x32.png",
        "icons/128x128.png",
        "icons/128x128@2x.png",
        "icons/icon.icns",
        "icons/icon.ico"
      ],

app file:


Make sure to delete the src-tauri/target/ folder and restart your machine. The Windows icon cache tends to be a bit annoying.

Thank you for your response @FabianLars. i tried this but it still shows that default icons
app icons and system tray icons working fine only thing .exe file icon not changing

For changing bundle icon for windows you have to set installerIcon like:
"bundle": {
    "windows": {
      "nsis": {
        "installerIcon": "icons/favicon.ico"
      }
    },
}


This updates the icon used in the installer but not the icon for the exe itself (at least for me)
